# DataTable filter: Get all the elements of the same group of the result

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datatable, grouping

I've filled the datagrid with a datatable. I can filter this datatable with rowfilter. I search the product and get the result. But I want to get also the other products in the same group.

**My Code**

```
<Window x:Class="Window1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Title="Window1" Height="129" Width="124" Loaded="Window_Loaded_1">
  <Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="testGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding GROUP}" Header="GROUP"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PRODUCT}" Header="PRODUCT"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
  </Grid>
</Window>

Private Sub Window_Loaded_1(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)

    'Create tabel
    Dim table As New DataTable
    table.Columns.Add("GROUP", GetType(String))
    table.Columns.Add("PRODUCT", GetType(String))
    table.Rows.Add("Group1", "Printserver")
    table.Rows.Add("Group1", "Recupel")
    table.Rows.Add("Group2", "Docking")
    table.Rows.Add("Group2", "Monitor")

    'Set Filter
    table.DefaultView.RowFilter = "PRODUCT like '%Monitor%'"

    'Fill Datagrid
    testGrid.DataContext = table

End Sub
```

Here is the screenshots of what I need:

[image: what I get] this would be ===>
[image: what I need]

How can I do this with datatable filter?

Comment: Don't use `System.Data` classes in WPF. Create a proper Data Model instead.

Comment: @HighCore Your are right but I've already started the project and not far from the deadline. Next time I will certainly use that.